# Force printing of all Acronyms, even those that have NOT been mentioned in the text

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Several acronyms that are not used (but are defined in the Acronym file) in my text are not shown in the List of Acronyms. How can I print all acronyms even if they are not used in the text. You can find related code lines that I used below:

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym]{glossaries}

\loadglsentries{acronyms}

%----- List of Acronyms -----%
\cleardoublepage        %\newpage
\phantomsection    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}
\printglossary[type=acronym, title=List of Acronyms]
%----------------------------%
```

By the way, I'm using pdflatex to build the pdf file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `\glsaddall` alone or with optional arguments as discussed on p. 105 of the user manual for the [`glossaries` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: Or `\glsaddallunused` when you want to add only the non-used ones.

Comment: many thanks for the fast resposne. the problem is solved.